# Define Log so that negative reals evaluate on lower edge of branch

Tags: functions, function-construction

I need to get *Mathematica* to evaluate the logarithm of a negative real number using the lower branch instead of the upper branch, so that while

```
In[1]:=   Log[3.2]
Out[1]:=  1.16315
```

I need

```
In[2]:=   Log[-3.2]
Out[2]:=  1.16315 - 3.14159 I
```

and not

```
Out[2]:=  1.16315 + 3.14159 I
```

I have already defined my own function `loopLog` that does this:

```
loopLog[x_: NumericQ] = If[Element[x,Reals], Conjugate[Log[x]]];
```

But I am not able to get it to perform any of the usual simplifications or manipulations using this function.  For example, when I want to differentiate loopLog, I get

```
In[3]:=   D[loopLog[x],x]
Out[3]:=  If[x \[Element] Reals, Derivative[1][Conjugate][Log[x]]/x]
```

Instead of the much needed `1/x`.  What is the cleanest way to define such a logarithm function in *Mathematica*?

Comment: `x_: NumericQ` this is a pattern that matches anything, but defaults to the symbol `NumericQ` if no argument is given. You surely meant `x_?NumericQ`

Comment: Would be nice with some `$BranchCut` global variable that affects `ArcTan` and the rest as well, even nicer if it could be set to an arbitrary curve.

Comment: @Rojo Yes, bad programing on my part.  It should have been `x_?NumericQ`

Comment: @ssch: Well, inspired by whuber's answer, here's a `Log` with a branch cut along any curve of the form $z = re^{i\theta(r)}$: `branchLog[z_, \[Theta]_] := 
 With[{r = Abs[z]}, Log[z/Exp[I \[Theta][r]]] + I \[Theta][r]]`. Then for `ArcTan` you can do `ExpToTrig[TrigToExp@ArcTan[z] /. Log[z_] -> branchLog[z, \[Theta]]]`...

Comment: Sorry, the branch is actually along $z=-re^{i\theta(r)}$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question asks for a "cleanest way." Arguably, any solution that reduces the calculation to various cases is not very clean, and is probably inefficient too. These considerations suggest a simple, direct approach:

```
log0[x_] := -Log[1/x]
```

Checking a few cases (or a plot) easily confirms that `log0` does what is intended with negative real numbers; *e.g.*,

```
log0[-3.2]
```

> 1.16315 - 3.14159 I

Moreover, it does not change the behavior for any other complex numbers, as a contour plot of its imaginary part demonstrates:

```
ContourPlot[Chop[Im[Log[x + I y]] -  Im[log0[x + I y]]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
  PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Contour plot]

Operators therefore produce the expected results:

```
D[log0[x], x]
```

> $\frac{1}{x}$

```
Integrate[x log0[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

> $\frac{i \pi }{2}$

Answer (score 3):

I never did this before (i.e. modify system function), but I just tried it, and it seems to work.  But I just wanted to first say, that `Log[z]` as it works in Mathematica is the correct way. i.e. `Log[z]=Log[Abs[z]]+k` where `k=0` when `z>0` and `k=I*Pi` when `z<0` so what you are asking to do is not the correct math way. But this is what I tried to change the definition

```
Log[-3.2]
(*1.1631508098056809 + 3.141592653589793*I*)

Unprotect[Log]
Log[x_?(Element[#, Reals] && # < 0 &)] := Log[Abs[x]] - I*Pi
Protect[Log]
Log[-3.2]
(*  1.1631508098056809 - 3.141592653589793*I  *)
```

and

```
Log[3.2]
(*  1.1631508098056809  *)
```

btw, the reason your `D[loopLog[x],x]` command did not work, is because you defined your function to accept only numerical `x`, but you are now taking derivative w.r.t `x` ? I do not think this will work.

Comment: "What you are asking to do is not the correct math way." They're just taking a slightly different branch cut from the usual one; it's hardly incorrect. There can be more than one right way in mathematics! :)

Comment: `_?(Element[#, Reals] && # < 0 &)` can simply be written as `_?Negative` :)

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi `Negative` and `Positive` were introduced in version 1, when such conventions were probably not codified. At this point, it is probably left that way for backwards compatibility.