# Defining dilogarithm with branch cut on $(-\infty,1)$

Tags: special-functions, complex

If my logarithms have a branch cut on $(0,\infty)$ then the dilogs constructed from these have a branch cut on $(-\infty,1)$. Is there a safe way to implement this in Mathematica? I tried with numerical integration but I couldn't get a stable result.

Comment: The branch point of dilog should still be at +1.

Comment: thanks, I mean $(-\infty,1)$

Comment: You might be interested in [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44767) and [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54434), on the subject of shifting branch cut locations.