# How does Mathematica understand branchcuts of the complex logarithm?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, series-expansion

Say I have the function $f(x) = x \tanh(\pi x) \log (x^2 +a^2)$ where $a$ is some positive real number. Then it seems to be me that *Mathematica* when given such a `Log[]` function implicitly puts a branch-cut along the positive imaginary axis starting at $x = ia$.

- Now if I ask *Mathematica* to integrate $f(x)$ along some semicircle in the upper half plane parametized as say, $x = A e^{i\phi}$ ($A>a$) for $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi$, then is *Mathematica*'s answer trustworthy?

Like did a large $A$ expansion (Series about $A=\infty$) and found that $xf(x)$ (that would practically be the integrand when converted into a $\phi$ integral), this function asymptotes as, $e^{2i\phi} \log(e^{2i\phi})A^2 + 2A^2 \log(A) + a^2$ (+ terms which go to zero as $A$ goes to infinity). Now on this asymptotic form the $\phi$ is integrable from $0$ to $\pi$ giving a finite answer.

So relying on this *Mathematica* result can I say that this integral therefore diverges in the large $A$ limit as $ \text{(number)} A^2 + \text{(number)} A^2 \log(A)$ ?

---

Like for example I chose $a=2$ and it seems to me that on using "NIntegrate" Mathematica says that the integral of this function on a circle centered at $2i$ goes to zero as the radius goes to 0.

Is this correct?

Thinking analytically this seems to be right...

Comment: The paper [Can your computer do complex analysis?](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/aslaksen/papers/cacas-2-2.pdf) is also relevant to this discussion.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The standard built-in logarithm function is defined for complex variables as follows:

```
Log[z] = Log[Abs[z]] + I Arg[z]
```

The location of the branch cut is simply caused by the convention that polar angles of `z` are assumed to be in the range $-\pi$ to $\pi$. This same branch cut is also part of the definition of the built-in `Arg` function.

Here is a different logarithm function called simply (lower-case) `log` to which you can supply a polar angle $\sigma$ at which the branch cut is going to be:

```
Clear[arg, log];
arg[z_, σ_: - Pi] := Arg[z Exp[-I (σ + Pi)]] + σ + Pi;
log[z_, σ_: - Pi] := Log[Abs[z]] + I arg[z, σ]
```

The first argument is the same as in the usual `Log` function. The second argument is optional, and if it's omitted then the new function agrees with its built-in counterpart. The default branch cut of the phase angle `arg` is $\sigma = -\pi$.

To illustrate these branch cut locations, I defined a "convenience function" that plots a function of the complex variable `z` in a square of side length `6` around the origin:

```
plot[f_] := Module[
  {fn = f /. z -> x + I y},
  Show[
   ContourPlot[
    Im[fn],
    {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
    ContourShading -> Automatic,
    ExclusionsStyle -> Red
    ],
   ContourPlot[
    Re[fn],
    {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
    ContourShading -> False,
    ContourStyle -> Blue,
    ExclusionsStyle -> Red
    ],
   FrameLabel -> {"Re(z)", "Im(z)"},
   Background -> Lighter[Orange],
   PlotRangePadding -> 0,
   PlotLabel -> 
    Framed[Grid[{{Style["-", Bold, Blue], 
        "Real part"}, {Style["-", Bold, Gray], "Imaginary part"}}, 
      Alignment -> Left], FrameStyle -> None, Background -> White, 
     RoundingRadius -> 5],
   ImageSize -> 300
   ]
  ]
```

For example, see the location of the branch cuts (**red**) rotate from the default to a non-standard direction:

```
GraphicsRow[{plot[Log[z]],plot[log[z,π/4]]}]
```

[image: log]

But now look at your function, with `a = 1` because that constant is irrelevant:

```
plot[z Tanh[π z] Log[z^2 + 1]]
```

[image: branch cuts vertical]

Here, the default choice of branch cut of the `Log` function leads to vertical branch cuts in the complex plane. This means the upper half plane is not a safe place to be integrating in...

Depending on your needs, you could try to change the branch cut location to something else by using the `log` function with an appropriate choice for $\sigma$.

Here is where the freedom of choice in the function `log` comes in. Try this:

```
plot[z Tanh[π z] log[z^2 + 1, 0]]
```

[image: cuts moved]

And as you can see, the branch cuts are now in a different position, no longer cutting through the middle of your integration domain.

**Edit: consequences for integration**

The question states that an integral along a semicircle in the upper half plane is to be performed, and the integrand now could be one of these two functions, corresponding to the default branch cut and the rotated branch cut shown in the previous image. Here I define them as functions:

```
f[z_] := z Tanh[π z] Log[z^2 + 1];
g[z_] := z Tanh[π z] log[z^2 + 1, 0]
```

The question further asks whether the result of the integration is "trustworthy." The answer is yes, but you have to know what exactly you're asking *Mathematica* to do. Therefore, I'll add some different plots just to clarify what I already said above. Pick a radius for your integration contour:

```
r = 6.2;
```

This is chosen to be not too large so as to obscure things, but also to avoid hitting one of the singularities of the `Tanh` functions which appear at regular intervals along the imaginary axis.

Now plot the two functions versus the polar angle in the interval corresponding to the upper half plane, and look at the numerical integrals of the two:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Re[#], Im[#]} &@f[r Exp[I ϕ]]], {ϕ, 
  0, Pi}]
```

[image: semicircle1]

```
NIntegrate[f[r Exp[I ϕ]], {ϕ, 0, Pi}]

(* ==> 20.271 - 3.55271*10^-15 I *)
```

This integral is perfectly allowable, but since it goes over the branch cut, you probably get something you didn't expect: in this case, a vanishing real part due to the cancelation of the area under the magneta, discontinuous curve. *Mathematica* doesn't produce a warning because isolated discontinuities are integrable. So is this result "trustworthy"? Sure. Do you want it? That's up to you.

Compare this to the function I suggested earlier:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Re[#],Im[#]}&@g[r Exp[I ϕ]]],{ϕ,0,π}]
```

[image: semicircle2]

```
NIntegrate[g[r Exp[I ϕ]], {ϕ, 0, Pi}]

(* ==> 58.2644 + 37.6991 I *)
```

Now you're integrating over a continuous function, and that's true for any given `r` as long as it avoids the isolated singularities.

This result is also "trustworthy." Unfortunately, I can't tell from the question if this is what's needed. In any case, since the asymptotic behavior of both functions is divergent at large `r` (which answers the other question in the post), the integral along a semicircle would have to be done at finite radius.

From the comment I am guessing that the goal is somehow to apply Cauchy's theorem, which is perfectly OK, although in this problem it doesn't yield any benefit. Nevertheless, if this is the goal then you definitely have to avoid crossing branch cuts with the integration contour. So which of the cuts is a better choice in this situation? The answer is: `g[z]`, because even though the branch cut now extends along the real axis, you can certainly draw a closed contour that completes the semicircle by hugging the cuts from above.

When doing this, you also end up having to calculate the integral over an infinitesimal circle around the branch point at $z = i$. By doing a series expansion of the factors around $z = i$ you can see that the integrand goes to zero and hence the integral is also zero. This answers the last question (which is not related to the choice of branch cuts).

**Edit 2**

Just for fun, here is how the branch cuts of the different logarithm functions evolve into each other as I change the parameter $\sigma$:

```
frames = Table[
   plot[z Tanh[Pi z] log[z^2 + 1, σ]], {σ, 
    0, Pi, Pi/16}];

ListAnimate[Join[Reverse[frames], frames], AnimationRepetitions -> 1]
```

[image: cuts]

The `GIF` was actually created with:

```
Export["cuts.gif",Join[Reverse[frames],frames],
  ImageResolution>72,AnimationRepetitions->Infinity,"DisplayDurations"->.1]
```

Comment: Thanks or this amazing answer - I simply don't know so much Mathematica! Can you say if my conclusions were right that I got using Mathematica about the $A$ dependence and the vanishing of the integral about the branchpoint?

Comment: In your last plot all the red lines are branch cuts -right? Then you have moved the branchcut along the x-axis? That will complicate matters - because I want to understand via complex analysis what is the behaviour of the integral of the function along the real line - thats the main objective...

Comment: I may have time to get back to this later, but in the meantime you may want to look at this post: [How to calculate contour integrals with Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34073/245)

Comment: @user6818 I added more information to my answer, although I had to guess what it is that you really want to know.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts! So if I let the branchcut be the default - as in upwards along the positive imaginary axis starting from point $ai$ then doing this contour integration on the UHP semicircle would have entailed taking a key-hole contour with the hole about the branchpoint and a semicircular bump about each pole on the positive imaginary axis on both sides of the key etc - so is Mathematica's answer when asked to integrate $f$ (your notation) along the semicircle the same? I mean when Mathematica is integrating $f$ is it taking into account the branch point at $ai$ and poles of Tanh?

Comment: And how do I understand your $\sigma$ - what is the graphical/physical significance of that number? How do I see that physically/graphically? Is there a geometrical way to see this $\sigma$? Why did you think of it?

Comment: *Mathematica* cannot know along which contour you want to integrate. You have to tell it. Your question is about *Mathematica*'s understanding of branch cuts of `Log`, and I explained that they arise from the phase angle convention. But `Log` is only one of infinitely many choices for the inverse of the `Exp` function, and all others can be generated by fixing a different $\phi$ interval for the phase angles. The quantity $\sigma$ is the lower bound of that interval of length $2\pi$, as seen in the definition of `log` above. It's pretty standard textbook stuff, but looks nice in your example.

Comment: If Mathematica is not choosing a contour then how is it computing the contour integral? Is there any valid meaning to this integral without a choice of branch avoiding contour and an associated limiting prescription? Thats is why I asked if Mathematica's answer is something meaningful? Because if it is not choosing a proper branch avoiding contour and a limiting process, it means it doesn't understand what a branch-cut is - right? Because technically one cannot just integrate across a branch-cut - right?

Comment: @user6818 No, that's not quite right. The choice of contour in complex integration is actually the way in which you, the user, define the quantity you want *Mathematica* to compute. This is becoming more of a math discussion, so I don't think it's fruitful to continue in the context of the original question.

Comment: For full flexibility, you might consider generalizing `arg[]` and `log[]` so that one can choose them to be continuous either from above or below the chosen branch cut.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. not sure what you mean. Do you want a multivalued function?

Comment: Currently. `Log[]` is "continuous from above", because evaluating it at the branch cut gives a result with positive imaginary part. To get the corresponding function that is "continuous from below", we use `-Log[1/z]`, as whuber demonstrated in another answer, where evaluating at the cut gives a result with negative imaginary part. (Sometimes you'll see the notation $\log(-x\pm i0)=\log\, x \pm i\pi$ denoting this choice of continuity.) I'm thinking your `arg` and `log` can use this additional flexibility. :)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is already included in my definition. You just have to change the angle $\sigma$ by $2\pi$. E.g., $\sigma=0$ and $\sigma=-2\pi$ are what I think you call continuous from above and below (I just don't think one should call this *above* and *below* because that's ambiguous for non-horizontal branch cuts).

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to @Jens' solution is to add the phase to the argument of the [`Log`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log) instead, and then remove the associated rotation in the output of the [`Log`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log):

```
logbranch[σ_] := With[{phase = I (σ + Pi)},
    Function[Log[# Exp[-phase]] + phase]
]
```

I used a slightly different definition so that you just replace [`Log`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log) with `logbranch[ϕ]` instead of replacing `Log[z]` with `log[z, ϕ]`

Here is a side-by-side [`ComplexPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexPlot) of the two versions for a branch cut along the positive real axis:

```
log0 = logbranch[0];
GraphicsRow[{
    ComplexPlot[log[z,0], {z, -2-2I, 2+2I}],
    ComplexPlot[log0[z], {z, -2-2I, 2+2I}]
}]
```

[image]