# Getting Arg[z] to go from $0$ to $2\pi$

Tags: function-construction, complex

I'm defining branch cut functions, and I'm using $\arg(z)$ as a building block. So I just spent an hour at the whiteboard assuming that $\arg(z)$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, and then I implement the code, and everything goes horribly wrong.

I just realized that the problem is that the the `Arg` function built into *Mathematica* goes from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. Is there anyway I can redefine `Arg` so that my code will work?

Comment: `arg[z_] /; Im[z] < 0 := Arg[z] + 2 Pi;  arg[z_] /; Im[z] >= 0 := Arg[z]`

Comment: See also the `arg` I use [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44769/245).

Comment: See also this answer [How to calculate contour integrals with Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34073/how-to-calculate-contour-integrals-with-mathematica/34090#34090) regarding closely related branch cuts.

Comment: [RELATED](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5782/13)

Comment: `arg[z_] := Pi+ArcTan[Re[z],Im[z]]`

Answer (score 3):

Let me test several versions of the redefined `arg`:

```
x = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, 1000000];

arg1[x_] := Mod[Arg@x, 2 π];
arg2[x_] := Arg[-x] + π;
arg3[z_] := π + ArcTan[-Re[z], -Im[z]];

Max[Abs[arg1[x] - arg2[x]], Abs[arg1[x] - arg3[x]]]
(* 8.88178*10^-16 *)

arg1[x]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.16715, Null} *)

arg2[x]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.154602, Null} *)

arg3[x]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.090001, Null} *)
```

It is surprising to me that `ArcTan` works sufficiently faster then `Arg`.

However, I do not recommend to redefine the build-in `Arg`. Sometimes it works

```
Block[{Arg = arg3}, Arg[Exp[-I]]]
(* -1 + 2 π *)
```

and sometimes not (why?)

```
Block[{Arg = arg3}, Plot[Arg@Exp[I φ], {φ, -2 π, 2 π}]]
```

[image]

Comment: The `Block` thing is an issue with the way `Compile` is used on the expression being plotted. You can fix it by setting the (undocumented?) `Compiled` option for `Plot` to `False`, or by moving the `Block` into the `Plot` statement. Either way, I think it's probably a bug and definitely worth a question of its own....

Comment: Did you copy the timings correctly?  On my machine Mac OS X 10.11, `ArcTan` is definitely slower than `Arg` in Mathematica 10.4, 10.3, 9.0 and 8.0.4.  On 10.3 they timings are `{0.016644, 0.025684, 0.090886}` on my machine.

Comment: @QuantumDot Yes, I obtain almost the same timings in v9 and `{0.10717, 0.087667, 0.10717}` in v10.3. The ratios between timings can be machine specific. I tested on my old laptop with Core 2 Duo under Linux.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** See comment below by Daniel, his answer is better. I shied away from using `ArcTan[]` because the previous comments mentioned problems with it, but it seems to work fine... Also I have since noticed a problem with my version where pure reals also get a `2π` shift.

### My previous comment:

So I stumbled upon this thead looking for the same answer as OP. While the answers here work, they are orders of magnitude slower than using the built in Arg[]. This is what I could come up with to solve my problem:

```
argVec[zVec_] := Module[{imShift},
 imShift = Unitize[(Sign /@ Im[zVec] - 1)]*(2π//N);
 Arg[zVec] + imShift];
```

This is only about 2x slower than the Arg[] function and it was the best I could come up with. I built it specifically to work with lists, just like Arg[], but it works just as well with scalars. The `//N` is needed to maintain the speed since my input `zVec` is machine precision, and I want machine precision output, however you can remove the `//N` and you will also get integer output for integer input, at the cost of speed.

Cheers!

Comment: Somewhat faster using `Mod`: `Mod[ArcTan[Re[z], Im[z]], 2.*Pi]`.

Answer (score 0):

From a comment by Artes, this seemed to solve the problem for the OP:

```
arg[z_] /; Im[z] < 0 := Arg[z] + 2 Pi; arg[z_] /; Im[z] >= 0 := Arg[z]
```