# How to calculate residues using different branches of the logarithm

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

My goal is to be able to compute the residues of something like $z^{\alpha} R(z)$ where $0 < \alpha < 1$, $R(z)$ is rational, and the exponential can be chosen with any branch.

I found a way to define the logarithm with any branch here:

[How does Mathematica understand branchcuts of the complex logarithm?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44767/how-does-mathematica-understand-branchcuts-of-the-complex-logarithm)

But when I input

```
Clear[arg, log];
arg[z_, σ_: - Pi] := Arg[z Exp[-I (σ + Pi)]] + σ + Pi;
log[z_, σ_: - Pi] := Log[Abs[z]] + I arg[z, σ]
```

and something as simple as

```
Residue[log[z, 0], {z, I}]
```

(i.e. using the branchcut $[0, 2\pi]$) which should just give $0$, as the function is analytic around $i$, I get the output

```
(* Residue[I (π + Arg[-z]) + Log[Abs[z]], {z, I}] *)
```

In other words, nothing happens.  I also tried numerically using `NResidue` but the same thing happens.  The problem is the same when I input the expressions of interest to me, such as ($\alpha = 1/3, R(z) = 1/(z^2+1)$)

```
Residue[Exp[(1/3) log[z, 0]]/(z^2 + 1), {z, I}]
```

which outputs

```
(* Residue[E^(1/3 (I (π + Arg[-z]) + Log[Abs[z]]))/(1 + z^2), {z, I}] *)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 7):

This is because *Mathematica* doesn't have definitions for the derivative of `Abs` and `Arg`, so it can't do series expansions of expressions containing them. Consequently, it doesn't evaluate the `Residue` of such expressions either. But you could define a new function `residue` that knows how to extract the harmless logarithm before going on:

```
Clear[arg, log];
arg[z_, σ_: - Pi] := 
  Arg[z Exp[-I (σ + Pi)]] + σ + Pi;
log[z_, σ_: - Pi] := Log[Abs[z]] + I arg[z, σ]

ClearAll[residue];
SetAttributes[residue, HoldAll]
residue[x_, var_] := 
 Residue[Unevaluated[x] /. a_log :> Limit[a, Rule @@ var], var]
```

Here are two examples, first the conventional branch cut, then your example:

```
residue[2 log[2 z + 2]/z, {z, 0}]

(* ==> 2 Log[2] *)

residue[Exp[(1/3) log[z, 0]]/(z^2 + 1), {z, I}]

(* ==> -(1/2) (-1)^(2/3) *)
```

I didn't put in any checks for existence of the `Limit` that I take in `residue`. I assume you'll choose the expansion point such that it doesn't conflict with the branch choice.

**Explanation**

The purpose of `residue` is to implement the relation $\text{res}_{z0}\left(f(z)\,g(z)\right)= \text{res}_{z0}\left(g(z0)\,f(z)\right)$ if $g(z)$ has no singularity at $z0$. In particular, it assumes that we have chosen the branch cut such that any term involving `log` (as defined above) can be treated as if it were such a $g(z)$. Really, what this does is to turn $g$ into a constant factor that could be pulled out.

To be able to pull out such terms from under the original `residue`, I give this new function the `HoldAll` attribute (`HoldFirst` would also work here). This is necessary so that the previously given definition for `log` is not used until *after* I'm done extracting it from the residue (otherwise we would at that point end up with `Abs` and `Arg` inside `Residue`, which halts the evaluation).

The extraction of `log` happens with a replacement rule, where I look for any object with `Head` equal to `log` inside the `Unevaluated` form of the input expression. By matching only the `Head` without looking into the arguments of `log`, I prevent the evaluator from kicking in (it would do that because `Unevaluated` is a "temporary" construct, not like `Hold`; but it's sufficient here).

Having identified the `log` with a dummy name `a`, I then evaluate it and replace any occurrence of the variable that was specified in `var` by its value at the expansion point. The argument `var` is of the form `{z, z0}`, so it's easy to do this replacement by writing it as a `Limit` for `z -> z0`. This is what `Rule @@ var` is for. At that stage, the evaluation of the enclosing `Residue` can proceed, with `log` having been turned into a constant. You could do similar replacements not just for `log` but also for other functions that prevent `Residue` from working, if you know they have no poles.

Comment: Could you say a bit about the inner workings of `residue`?  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey OK, I've added an explanation.